# what is something like %2 in unicode

Tags: python, unicode

I am reading from someone else and come to the part concerning unicode, which is always a headache for me. That will really help a lot if you can give some hints.

The situation is so:
I have a stopword file named stopword.txt in the form of following:

```
         1   781037 
         2   650706 damen
         3   196100 löwe
         4   146044 lego
         5   138280 monster
         6   136410 high
         7   100657 kost%c3%bcm   #this % seems to be strange already
         8    94084 schuhe
         9    93680 kinder
         10   87308 mit
```

and the code trying to read in it, look likes:

```
     with open('%s/%s'%('path_to_stopwords.txt'), 'r') as f:
          stoplines = [line.decode('utf-8').strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

this decode('utf-8') seems to be very mysterious to me. As my understanding, without extra 
specification "open" method read in files as string which will be automated encoded as 
ascii (so in this case it causes already information loss if file which is opened contains character whose code point outside of 128, like löwe and it is read into program with encoding ascii, because then ö will be truncated encoded?) What the meaning of trying decoding it into utf-8 after reading into program ?

And to verify my ideas, I have tried to check what is in each line now with codes.

```
    for line in stoplines:
        print line
```

which gives me:

```
    %09
    %21%21%21
    %26
    %26amp%3b
    %28buch%29
    %28gr.
    %2b
    %2bbarbie
```

I am quite confused where these % comes from. Have I correctly read in the context of file ?

Thnak you very much

Comment: why are you using `'%s/%s'%('path_to_stopwords.txt')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, when you open a file and read from it, you get an `str` instance back, not a `unicode` string (in Python 3, you'd get a `str`, which is unicode in Python 3).

`str.decode('utf-8')` lets you decode that `str` into a `unicode` string (assuming the encoding is UTF8!).

It seems like your stopwords are [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding):

```
print urllib.unquote('%c3%bc')
ü
```

It is indeed redundant to use urlencoding if the file is supposed to be UTF8 (which natively supports characters such as `ü`), but my intuition would be that this file is in fact ASCII, not UTF8.

All ASCII chars map to the same char in UTF8, so this works, despite being wrong.

Answer (score 1):

A few points:

1. If the file is UTF-8, you should open *all* of it as UTF-8, not line by line. Either read it all and then decode (i.e f.read().decode("utf-8")) or open it using [codecs.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) with UTF-8.
2. You don't need f.readlines(), you can simple do "for line in f". It's more memory efficient and shorter.
3. '%s/%s'%('path_to_stopwords.txt') does not even work. Make sure you're doing it correctly. You might want to use os.path.join to join the paths.
4. The % encoding is url encoding. As Thomas above me wrote, you can use urllib.unquote.